# How to safely remove snaps installed by apt transitional packages?

Tags: apt, snap

How do I safely uninstall snaps which are installed by transitional packages? For example I upgraded a system from 20.04 to 22.04 which had chromium-browser installed.  As a result, chromium-browser was upgraded to:

`rc  chromium-browser                              1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.2                 amd64        Transitional package - chromium-browser -> chromium snap`

Which resulted in /snap/chromium being populated

I now need to uninstall this.  I `apt-get remove`'d the `chromium` and `chromium-browser` packages (then `apt-get autoremove`'d all orphaned dependencies), however /snap/chromium did not get smaller.  `dpkg -l | grep chromium` still shows the `chromium-browser` line shown above.

what is the right way to remove this snap, without apt transitional packages getting out-of-sync?

I ask because I have a bunch of other /snap/* directories I want to clean up to recover disk space on this smaller aging system, however they must have been installed by apt and I do not want to remove the snap packages directly.

Comment: `chromium` converted to *snap* package prior to 20.04, thus it was a *snap* package in 20.04 & no conversion or change occurred on *release-upgrade* to later releases than 20.04 as *snap* packages don't change. If you note your paste it was installed at 20.04 as if the change occurred at 22.04 you would have pasted `1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu2`

Comment: Ok thanks, perhaps I included enough details to distract from my real question.

Does APT track snap packages after the transition? Or are they just snap, and I can remove them safely via snap directly without apt getting out of sync? @guiverc

Comment: Apt knows nothing about snap packages, and apt cares nothing about snap packages. You can safely remove transition packages at any time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Transitional" packages do not include application files. They are essentially just a script that runs `snap install <snap-package-name>` and possibly copies any user data to the new location in ~/.snap/.

- **After a transitional package has been installed once, it's done**. Running it's script and installing the snap are part of the apt install process -- you DON'T need to "run" it or "launch" it; apt did it for you already. It's job is finished.
- Installing the snap does NOT require the transitional apt package; you can simply `snap install <snap-name>` yourself. if you wish.
- The transitional package can be safely removed at any time...or safely left installed. Apt won't complain because transitional packages have no deb dependencies.

How to remove a transitional package:

```
sudo apt remove <transitional-package>
```

Transitional packages are a one-way trip. **You cannot remove snap packages by using apt**. Removing the apt package WON'T remove the snap, and removing the apt package won't break anything.

If you want to remove the snap package, use the `snap` command.

To remove the newly-installed snap:

```
sudo snap remove <snap-package-name>
```

- If you don't know the snap package name, run `snap list` to see what snaps are installed.
- The transitional apt package won't care if you remove the snap. However, if the apt package is installed, it might try to reinstall the snap in the future.

Comment: Thank you -- so to confirm, `snap remove` won't piss off apt (make its metadata/state inconsistent, upsetting dependency resolutions or future uninstallation/reinstallation options of packages), because the transitional packages were one-way?  They installed the snap, and have zero involvement after that?